# Empty object check

Tags: c#

Is there a way to know if all the properties in an object are empty. My object represents fields from database and I want to know if a particular record is present or not. NULL doesnt seem to work.

Comment: Need more info. How are you pulling the object? ADO.Net, Linq-to-Sql, NHinbernate, something else?

Comment: I am using NHibernate to pull the data from database.

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried checking against **DBNull.Value**

Comment: I am using NHibernate to fetch the data. Can you explain me what will DBNull.Value do, and if my object is User how will I check against it?

Answer (score 3):

You can use reflection:

```
public static bool IsEmptyEntity<T>(T obj)
{
    foreach (var property in typeof(T).GetProperties())
        if (property.GetValue(obj, null) != null)
            return false;
    return true; 
}
```

Usage:

```
    public class MyTestEntity
    {
        public string Str { get; set; }
        public int? Int { get; set; }
    }

MyTestEntity test = new MyTestEntity();
var empty = IsEmptyEntity(test); //returns true
```

Answer (score 0):

If the record is not present, then why would you have an object to represent it?

Comment: I have a button called Create Profile for user. I am binding my visibility property of button to the Profile object. When I click on the Create Profile button, I am having a construtor open the window which creates empty object with null values. So the button changes to Edit Profile eventhough I have not inserted anything in the database.

Comment: @developer: I think a better design would be to have a CreateMode flag on the form. Create Profile would set the flag to true. Use the flag to decide whether to change the button, not whether the object is empty. This way the button text will follow directly from your intention (the flag is set if you're creating) and not from a side-effect (the object is only empty if you are creating).

Answer (score 0):

If your `object represents fields from database`, then it's probably a collection. If so, you can most likely use an extension method like `myCollection.Any()` to see if there are any objects inside the collection. Is that what you are asking for?

Answer (score 0):

A lot of languages use a method or property called `IsEmpty` for this kind of check.  During the hydration phase of the object set a boolean flag that specifies if the object is empty or not.  Then you can simply use the property or method elsewhere to check for empty objects.

ie

During hydration

```
bool _isEmpty = false;

if( prop1 is empty && prop2 is empty )
{
  _isEmpty = true;
}
else
{
  _isEmpty = false;
}
```

Then use an `IsEmpty` property

```
IsEmpty
{
   get { return _isEmpty; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found occasions where using just a check with DBNull isn't enough.  Maybe not the purest approach but a temporary check as a string seems to do the trick.  Like so:

```
    if ((DBNull.Value != field) &&
        (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(field.ToString())))
```